# SQL queries alternative in DAX

Tags: c#, .net, ssas, dax, tabular

I have an asp.net core (.net 5) project that I connected to SSAS and I run DAX query on tabular tables

I had two questions:

1 - Is it possible to change tabular tables column data type using DAX (something like alter table in SQL)

2 - Is it possible to determine the relationship between tables using DAX (such as foreign key in SQL column)

I use this package to connect to SSAS and run DAX queries :

https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AnalysisServices.AdomdClient.NetCore.retail.amd64/19.21.0

If this is not possible with DAX, can you tell me what else I can do?

Comment: 1) DAX is a read-only query language; it does not have DML statements like SQL does. You can, however, generate new tables on the fly, which takes the place of changing source data. To actually change the model, you would need XMLA. 2) DAX does not do metadata discovery either; for this you need to query the appropriate [views](https://learn.microsoft.com/analysis-services/instances/use-dynamic-management-views-dmvs-to-monitor-analysis-services). It does have functions like `USERELATIONSHIP` to define relationships on the fly.

Comment: In the above, for "DML", read "DDL", I always get them mixed up. :P